# Custom plot for specific dataSet

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, subplot

I started to learn python and investigate the task about creation a plot for all series by each date:

```
                                    f_ec24.67   f_ec452   f_ec452.1 
    date    date_1  date_2  date_3                                  
    2012    1962:Q2 2012    1962:Q2     1          77        1519       
    2013    1962:Q3 2013    1962:Q3     77         464        766       
    2014    1962:Q4 2014    1962:Q4     7           7           4           
    2015    1963:Q1 2015    1963:Q1     8         2137         63           
    2016    1963:Q2 2016    1963:Q2     9           94         25
```

I tried to complete it by the way with the following code:

```
    max_values.plot(legend=None)
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.title("Max plot")
    plt.xlabel("Dates")
    plt.ylabel("Max-Values")
    plt.show()
```

In result, I received some mess on the Ox axis of the plot, how can I customize plot in this case?

[image: exampleplot]

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xticks-labels are overlapping. You could try to solve it by rotating them:

```
plt.xticks(rotation=70)
```